# Error on Not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#

Anything wrong with my code? Im not quite sure how to fix it. It has been bugging me for days, I cant sleep and eat peacefully. Help me. Im dying. I may be exaggerating but they said my post is mostly coding, I have to add more details. Still this isnt enough?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    dailyspend(ref totalspendf, ref totalspendc, ref totalspendcr, ref totalspendo);
}


static double dailyspend(ref double totalspendf, ref double totalspendc, ref double totalspendcr, ref double totalspendo)
{ 
    int days;
    double spendf = 0, spendc = 0, spendcr = 0, spendo = 0;
    for (days = 1; days <= 7; days++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write("Food : ");
        spendf = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Clothing : ");
        spendc = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("College related : ");
        spendcr = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Outside: ");
        spendo = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("");
        totalspendf += spendf;
        totalspendc += spendc;
        totalspendcr += spendcr;
        totalspendo += spendo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the return statement for `dailyspend` method?

Comment: You've answered the question in the title! In all seriousness, you can either return the total value or make your function static void dailyspend... rather than static double.

Comment: Well real simple, `static double dailyspend` means you should return a double. You aint doing that

Comment: Yeap, I just realised that. I should have change it to "void". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your method `dailyspend()` specifies that it will return a `double`, but nowhere does it call `return`.

Add `return` + the value that should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because your method should return a `double` as defined in the signature. However it does not return anything as you do not provide any information on which value you want to return. A method can have only one or no return-value, however I guess you want your method to return four values which does not work - at least not using `return`.

I assume you won´t need any return-value for your method. So chaning the methods return-type to `void` should work for you. However you still have to declare all the variables within `Main` before you can pass them by reference.

```
static void dailyspend(ref double totalspendf, ref double totalspendc, ref double totalspendcr, ref double totalspendo)
{ 
    int days;
    for (days = 1; days <= 7; days++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write("Food : ");
        double spendf = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Clothing : ");
        double spendc = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("College related : ");
        double spendcr = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Outside: ");
        double spendo = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("");
        totalspendf += spendf;
        totalspendc += spendc;
        totalspendcr += spendcr;
        totalspendo += spendo;
    }
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
double totalspendf = 0, totalspendc = 0, totalspendcr = 0, totalspendo = 0;
dailyspend(ref totalspendf, ref totalspendc, ref totalspendcr, ref totalspendo)
```

Now you can do anything with the four parameters passed by reference, e.g.

```
Console.WriteLine(totalspendf);
```

Which should print the sum of all the inputs made for `Food` within your method.

Answer (score 0):

If you've declared a method as anything other than `void` or `Task`, you need to ensure all possible code paths has a valid `return`, or throws an `Exception`.

For your function `dailyspend`, luckily you only have one possible code path, so you need to simply add in a `return` anywhere down the line (I'd imagine you'd want it to be the line directly beneath your `for` loop.